# Почему опрератор сравнения в javascript сравнивает только первые цифры у чисел?

Tags: javascript, html, php

```
if (value > st_value){
    $('#pol'+i).after($('#pol'+znach_id)); 
} else if ( value < st_value ){
    $('#pol'+i).before($('#pol'+znach_id)); 
}
```

Когда в переменные приходят 4 и 5 допустим,то всё работает нормально,но когда 2 и 15,то сравниваются 2 и 1 в итоге получается 2>15.
Почему так происходит?

Comment: потому что приходят строки, а не числа

Comment: Блин,извиняюсь за тупой вопрос!В других функциях делал parseInt по этому проблем не было,а тут забыл.Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @Ринат Давлетбаев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего ты сравниваешь строки, а не числа
Прежде чем сравнивать, приведи значения, которые берешь к типу integer, например с помощью parseInt()
parseInt(value,10) 
parseInt(st_value,10) 
А потом уже производи сравнения

Comment: Спасибо.Уже разобрался.Когда переменную получал в число не перевёл.